# Add a class/id to a single.php wordpress pagination link

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, anchor

I have a piece of code to grab the query string and continue to carry it throughout the pagination of a single post. The problem is I can't find a way to select the pagination links  correctly to apply this code to it. Here is the code for the query string:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Gets the query string
    var query_string = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?'));

    // Appends query string to each pagination link
    $('li.testlink a').each(function () {
         var href = $(this).attr('href');
         $(this).attr('href', href + query_string);
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem is where it says `li.testlink a`, I can't get it to select the anchor tag of the pagination link:

```
<li class="testlink">
    <a href="http://lmfaofacts.com/top-10-strongest-animal-bites/">
        <span class="page-numbers">Previous page</span>
    </a>
    <a href="http://lmfaofacts.com/top-10-strongest-animal-bites/3/">
        <span class="page-numbers">Next page</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Any idea on how I could either append a class to that anchor tag to select it or another method? Just simply using a CSS style selector with `<div>`s/`<li>`s doesn't seem to work. Thank you!

Comment: it should work fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QXXec/2/

Comment: check the value of `query_string ` to make sure it is having the correct value

Comment: Yeah I wasn't using the query_string value before. I'm not sure if this helps me or not. If no query string is present in the URL, this site will display the standard ad code. If say ?id=matt, it displays Matt's ad code. However, the problem with using the extra string is that it doesn't carry across multiple pages. Going from lmfaofacts.com/?id=matt to lmfaofacts.com/2/, the string doesn't carry over. This code seemed to be the solution, but the selector isn't working. It doesn't let me select the next page link to apply that to. Biggest problem making it work with wordpress.